# EF - Foreign Key Reinserted if Entity Object is Used

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I have this problem with EF when I create objects which have FK reference on another object that was retrieved from DB but from different DB context (see GetBlog method). The problem is that whenever I try to insert this FK references along with the main object, the FK reference is recreated.

One solution is that I can use the ID of the FK objectwhich works, but I would like to know if it is possible to do the insert using the entire object as demonstrated in the example below without duplicating the FK object.

I tried db.Blogs.Attach(fkBlog) but that did not help. Neither did setting the object state to Added/Unchanged. Any ideas?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using( var db = new BloggingContext() )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
            { 
                var blog = new Blog() { Name = i.ToString(), Description = "Desc", Url = String.Format( "http://{0}", i ) };

                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
            { 
                var fkBlog = GetBlog();

                var post = new Post()
                {
                    Blog = fkBlog,
                    Content = String.Format("Blog Content {0}", i),
                    Title = String.Format("Blog Title {0}", i)
                };

                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Blog GetBlog()
    {
        using( var db = new BloggingContext() )
        {
            return db.Blogs.OrderBy( x=>Guid.NewGuid() ).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

If I use the attach method (just under the entity is loaded), I receive the following error:

> Attaching an entity of type '...Blog' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Edit2: Attach actually fails because I am trying to attach the object inside a for loop. If I attach each blog only once OR if I always deatch the object after save all works.

Inlining is not an option in my case unfortunately. Im reliant on external data providers.

Comment: The above code does not try to Attach. It would be better if showing this attempt. Also make sure to indicate the version of EF.

Comment: You're working with 2 different Context objects, which is generally a bad idea. Try inlining the call to GetBlog(), I.E `var fkBlog = db.Blogs.OrderBy( x=>Guid.NewGuid() ).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 4):

You should either use the same context object:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using( var db = new BloggingContext() )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        { 
            var blog = new Blog() { Name = i.ToString(), Description = "Desc", Url = String.Format( "http://{0}", i ) };

            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        { 
            var fkBlog = db.Blogs.OrderBy( x=>Guid.NewGuid() ).FirstOrDefault();

            var post = new Post()
            {
                Blog = fkBlog,
                Content = String.Format("Blog Content {0}", i),
                Title = String.Format("Blog Title {0}", i)
            };

            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Or create two completely separate Contexts for the two operations:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using( var db = new BloggingContext() )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        { 
            var blog = new Blog() { Name = i.ToString(), Description = "Desc", Url = String.Format( "http://{0}", i ) };

            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    using( var db = new BloggingContext() )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        { 
            var fkBlog = GetBlog();
            db.Context.Attach(fkBlog);

            var post = new Post()
            {
                Blog = fkBlog,
                Content = String.Format("Blog Content {0}", i),
                Title = String.Format("Blog Title {0}", i)
            };

            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP did state *Inlining is not an option in my case unfortunately* though.

Comment: Which is strange, because what else is he going to do? If he can't make the change I proposed, what *can* he change? I was hoping OP could clarify what his options are. I added another option for good measure.

Comment: a private method that takes a DbContext which both methods call. That way the user of this class calls a wrapper method of the private one and the class's methods can decide which DbContext to use. Hope I made that clear :)

Comment: although, I think he needs the public GetBlog method. hm. I'll post my own answer to explain it

Comment: @Rik, Say that you are not owner of GetBlog and you cannot change it (and you dont even know what it does). What then? If it is not possible in EF then I am fine with that it is just that I cannot find any information regarding this.

Comment: @NeverStopLearning Try my second approach. It's a bit tricky to determine the solution here, because what happens in `GetBlog()` matters, particularly, how it uses the Context. You don't want 2 different Contexts fighting over control of the same entity. That's why I make sure to close the first context used for inserting Blogs before inserting posts in those blogs

Comment: Interesting idea, how is it different from calling GetBlog which internally uses using(...). It closes the context before returning from the function does it not?

Comment: It doesn, but once the Blog object is loaded from the Context (in `GetBlog()`), it needs to be attached to the other Context (the one in `Main`), but that one already has the Same entity attached to that, because it was just inserted.

Answer (score 3):

[Rik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30188071/238902) has a point - there's no need to use multiple `DbContexts` when you've already opened one. If you still need the `GetBlog` method you could work around this simply by using an internal method which accepts a DbContext as a parameter:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using( var db = new BloggingContext() )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        { 
            var blog = new Blog() { /* as before */ };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        { 
            var fkBlog = GetBlog(db);

            var post = new Post()
            {
                /* as before */
            };

            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public static Blog GetBlog()
{
    using(var db = new BloggingContext())
    {
        return GetBlog(db);
    }
}

private static Blog GetBlog(BloggingContext db)
{
    return db.Blogs.OrderBy(x=>Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to provide this answer, I will accept it if nothing better comes. However the original point of the question was a bit different. Say that you are not owner of GetBlog and you cannot change it. What then? If it is not possible in EF then I am fine with that it is just that I cannot find any information regarding this.

Comment: np. However, don't accept an answer just to accept. I misunderstood your problem, I thought there were external providers *using* the GetBlog method..! The problem boils down to not having two DbContexts open at the same time. Let me think about it.

Comment: Do you have a property `BlogId` in your `Post` model? In that case, try using your code but instead of `Blog = fkBlog` use `BlogId = fkBlog.Id`. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: the reason this would work is because the `fkBlog` is not fetched from the current DbContext, i.e. it is considered a new entity. But you inserted it before, thus a similar entity already exists. Using the Id is OK though, since that is just a column in the database. So, if this works for you I'll edit my answer to reflect this explanation.

Comment: Yeah using just ID is possible, if I understand your suggestion correctly I already tried that and it worked. (See "One solution is that I can use the ID of the FK objectwhich works...."). The question was really about if its possible to use the entire object or not. It still unclear to me why I cannot just say to EF: I have this object, it came from DB, it exists there already and it is unchanged.  But I am new to EF so there probably is a good reason for this.